# Grails3: The return type of java.lang.Boolean hasErrors() in AuthRoleController is incompatible with boolean in grails.artefact.Controller

Tags: java, grails, upgrade

I have upgrade my app from grails 2.5 to grails 3.3.11.I have followed all the step and everything seem to be fine,but when I run the app. I am having this error :

startup failed:
/home/server-dev/Documents/dev_repo/tms/grails-app/controllers/org/niport/auth/AuthRoleController.groovy: -1: The return type of java.lang.Boolean hasErrors() in org.niport.auth.AuthRoleController is incompatible with boolean in grails.artefact.Controller
. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Any idea or assistance will be helpfull, thanks a lot

------------------------AuthUserController.groovy ---------------------

```
     import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
        import grails.transaction.Transactional
        import org.niport.com.ComTrainingCenter
        import org.niport.com.ComTrainingCenterService
        import org.niport.com.FileService
        import org.niport.com.TrackerService
        import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
        
        import javax.imageio.ImageIO
        import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
        
        import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED
        import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK
        
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        class AuthUserController {
            private static final allowedImageType = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']
        
            SpringSecurityService springSecurityService
            AuthUserService       authUserService
            TrackerService        trackerService
            FileService           fileService
            def                   dateParseFormat,
                                  currentDate
            AuthUser currentUser
        @Transactional
        save(AuthUser userInstance) {
            if (userInstance == null) {
                flash.error = message(code: "default.message.noRecordFound.label", default: "Error-Save-AuthUser-L21 : Record not found...!")
                redirect(action: "create")
                return
            }
            
    
            userInstance.avatarType = params.attachment ? fileService.uploadFile("auth", "auth_user", userInstance?.username, "any", 1, 5000000, params.attachment) : null
            userInstance.createdBy = currentUser?.id
            userInstance.properties["hdCode"] = trackerService.getHdCode(params.password)
    
            userInstance.validate()
            if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
                flash.error = "Error-Save-AuthUser-L27 : " + userInstance.errors
                redirect(action: "create", userInstance: userInstance)
                return
            }
    
            try {
                userInstance.save(failOnError: true)
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                println "ex-user-sa-L112 : " + e
                flash.error = "Error-Save-AuthUser-L113 : " + e
                redirect(action: "create", userInstance: userInstance)
                return
            }
    
            request.withFormat {
                form multipartForm {
                    flash.success = message(code: "default.message.created", args: [message(code: "user.pageTitle.label", default: "AuthUser"), userInstance.id])
                    redirect userInstance
                }
                '*' { respond userInstance, [status: CREATED] }
            }
        }}

--------------------------AuthRoleController.groovy ----------------------
mport grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.validation.Validateable
//import grails.artefact.Controller 
//import java.lang.*

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK
class AuthRoleController implements Validateable {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT"]

    def springSecurityService, dateFormat, currentDate, currentUser

    def beforeInterceptor = {
        currentDate = new Date()
        currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        dateFormat  = grailsApplication.config.format.dtp.date
    }
 @Transactional
    def save(AuthRole roleInstance) {
        roleInstance.createdBy=(AuthUser)currentUser
        roleInstance.validate()
        if (roleInstance == null) {
            flash.error = message(code: "default.message.noRecordFound.label", default: "Error-Save-AuthRole-L21 : Record not found...!")
            redirect(action: "create")
            return
        }
        log.info "${roleInstance}";
        if (roleInstance.hasErrors()) {
            flash.error = "Error-Save-AuthRole-L27 : " + roleInstance.errors
            redirect(action: "create", roleInstance: roleInstance)
            return
        }

        try {
            roleInstance.save failOnError: true
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            flash.error = "Error-Save-AuthRole-L36 : " + e
            redirect(action: "create", roleInstance: roleInstance)
            return
        }

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.success = message(code: "default.message.created", args: [message(code: "role.pageTitle.label", default: "AuthRole"), roleInstance.id])
                redirect roleInstance
            }
            '*' { respond roleInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Does `org.niport.auth.AuthRoleController` have a method in it named `hasErrors`?  If no, does the controller explicitly extend any class or implement any traits?

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown this is just the instance of the Spring Error interace associated with the controller. But I can share the code of the associated controlles as the answers

Comment: This isn't related to your question but the code you have added points to another problem and that is your controller is not going to be compatible with concurrent requests because of the way you are handing `currentUser` in `AuthRoleController`.  That is going to be broken unless you configure your controllers to be request scoped, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

> class AuthRoleController implements Validateable

There is no good reason to have a controller implement the `Validateable` trait, and doing so will cause problems.

The issue is you are going to get 2 methods named `hasErrors`, one from https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/1979b62d0ef9ebbaa547c8744263376557a10459/grails-plugin-validation/src/main/groovy/grails/validation/Validateable.groovy#L58 and one from https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/1979b62d0ef9ebbaa547c8744263376557a10459/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/grails/artefact/Controller.groovy#L123, and they have different return types.

Comment: Removing `Validateable` from the controller won't cost you any capability.  Its presence isn't contributing anything helpful.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I will remove the Validateable interface and will let you now if it works